# Not able to run rake command because of bcrypt gem on Windows 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bcrypt

I have the following error related bcrypt gem dependency on my Windows 7 machine.

```
$ rake db:drop db:create db:schema:load db:migrate db:fixtures:load
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- bcrypt_ext
C:/nital/office-data/integration-services-projects/Payments/customer-portal-project/customer-portal/config/application.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
C:/nital/office-data/integration-services-projects/Payments/customer-portal-project/customer-portal/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- 2.2/bcrypt_ext
C:/nital/office-data/integration-services-projects/Payments/customer-portal-project/customer-portal/config/application.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
C:/nital/office-data/integration-services-projects/Payments/customer-portal-project/customer-portal/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)


$ ruby -v
ruby 2.2.4p230 (2015-12-16 revision 53155) [i386-mingw32]

$ rails --version
Rails 4.2.6

$ rake --version
rake, version 11.1.2
```

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'bcrypt-ruby',  '3.1.2'
gem 'bcrypt',       '3.1.8'
```

Please guide.

Comment: Your subject says you're not able to run a `bundle install`, but you didn't include the results of running `bundle install`...?

Comment: Apologize, as the subject line is incorrect. I will fix it right now.

Comment: Are you wedded to bcrypt-ruby 3.1.2? The latest is 3.1.5.